# How can i add another component by clicking a button on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here's my problem.
I have a premade component, which is a "line" of content, which contains some buttons and some input boxes.
Now, i want to add more of this exact component, whenever i press a button "add row", but i have no clue on how i can do this.
I know basic concepts like States, map ... but i don't know ho to put it on code.
Can someone explain me how can i do it ?

PS I'm really new to React, and in general to JS world

Here's the code

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import OpLine from "./Components/OpLine";



function App() {

  const addRowHandler = () => {

  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg">
        <button onClick={addRowHandler}> Add Row </button>
        <OpLine></OpLine>
        <div className="result">Result is : (resVar) </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

OpLine.js

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card/Card";
import './OpLine.css';
import OpForm from "./OpForm/OpForm";

const OpLine = () => {

    return(
        <Card className="line">   
            <OpForm></OpForm>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default OpLine;
```

OpForm.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./OpForm.css";

const OpForm = () => {
  return (
    <div className="op-form">
      {/*div handling op button*/}
      <div className="operando">
        <label>Operando</label>
        <select>
          <option>+</option>
          <option>-</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      {/*div handling number input button */}
      <div className="number-input">
        <label>Insert number</label>
        <input type="number"></input>
      </div>

      <button>Delete</button>

      <button>Disable</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OpForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your needs, but you can create a counter inside the state and iterate this in order to render the components.

Button will increment the counter

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

  const addRowHandler = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };
```

and in render method

```
{Array.from({length: counter}).map(() => <OpForm></OpForm>)}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-hooks-counter-forked-whxgq3?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about it as "adding a component" think of it as "updating state". The state then informs the main component how to render it.

Here's a small example where I'm using name, age, and role as property names. After you've added a couple of rows, and filled in some information, click the "Show state" to see the result.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise the state as an empty array
  const [ state, setState ] = useState([]);

  // When the `addRow` button is clicked, add a new
  // empty object to the state
  function addRow(e) {
    const object = { name: '', age: '', role: '' };
    setState([...state, object]);
  }

  // We pass this handler down to the Row component
  function handleChange(e) {

    // Check to see if the element that's changed
    // is an input
    if (e.target.matches('input')) {

      // Get the id from the div dataset
      const { id } = e.currentTarget.dataset;

      // Get the name and value from the changed element
      const { name, value } = e.target;

      // Copy the state
      const copy = [...state];

      // Create a new object using the object in state
      // at index === id, and update the correct property
      const obj = { ...state[id], [name]: value };

      // Add that object to the state copy
      copy[id] = obj;

      // Finally update the state
      setState(copy);
    }
  }

  // We now create some rows by mapping
  // over the data and returning an array
  // of components which have an id based
  // on their position in the state array, some
  // data contained in the object, and the handler
  function createRows(state) {
    return state.map((obj, i) => {
      return (
        <Row
          id={i}
          data={obj}
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  // Small function to show state when a
  // button is clicked
  function showState() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
  }

  // Check to see if state has length, and then
  // create the rows
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add a row</button>
      <button onClick={showState}>Show state</button>
      {state.length ? createRows(state) : <div />}
    </div>
  );

}

// Row accepts and id, some data, and the handler
function Row({ id, data, handleChange }) {

  // Destructure the information from `data`
  const { name, age, role } = data;

  // Build the Row JSX. Note that we add the
  // id as a data attribute on the div element
  return (
    <div
      data-id={id}
      className="row"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <label>Name
        <input name="name" value={name} />
      </label>
      <label>Age
        <input name="age" value={age} />
      </label>
      <label>Role
        <input name="role" value={role} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
input { margin-left: 0.5em; display: inline-block;}
.row { background-color: #efefef; padding: 0.3em; margin-top: 1em; }
button { margin-right: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```